How laser gain bandwidth is calculated?
I was reading about mode-locking from Wikipedia and there is an explanation of cavity modes. The following sentence confuses me:

For example, a typical helium–neon laser has a gain bandwidth of about 1.5 GHz (a wavelength range of about 0.002 nm at a central wavelength of 633 nm), whereas a titanium-doped sapphire (Ti:sapphire) solid-state laser has a bandwidth of about 128 THz (a 300 nm wavelength range centered at 800 nm)

Where do the 0.002 nm and 300 nm come from? How are they calculated?

According to the same page you linked,

the range of frequencies over which a laser may operate is known as the gain bandwidth

For an helium–neon laser with a wavelength range of about 0.002 nm at a central wavelength of 633 nm, we have that the interval of wavlengths in nm is 632.999–633.001. Using the speed of light to convert these two values to frequencies, you find that the corresponding interval of frequencies in GHz is 473605.0–473606.5, which indeed has a width (range) of 1.5 GHz.
So, answering your question, the 0.002 (nm) is not calculated, but a known value from which you calculate the 1.5 (GHz) as explained above.

Laser gain bandwidth is determined by the type of laser and the physical properties of the active material.
Very roughly explained, physically-realizable lasers cannot have very sharp lines as described by Heisenberg's uncertainty relation:
$\Delta E \geq \hslash/2 \Delta t \geq \hslash\omega $
These are due to vacuum fluctuations in the medium and are purely a quantum-mechanical effect. For a laser to occur, you need several levels to which you excite an atom, ion or molecule and then it stays in the excited state in what is called the natural lifetime, which is determined by the vacuum fluctuations.
Therefore, you will see 2 mechanisms for line broadening (how much bandwidth the laser has which has gain, or more explicitly, which wavelengths will be amplified and then form the laser line of choice): Homogeneous broadening, where all the ions, atoms or molecules have the same emission or absorption probability, and Inhomogeneous broadening, where interaction probabilities are different on the ions, atoms or molecules in the system. One of such effects is the doppler shift in gas lasers (A HeNe laser), where the local velocity of the atoms (Neon, in this case) will cause the local line broadening of the emission line.
For HeNe lasers, the doppler broadening is approximately:
$g(\nu_s) \sim 1/\nu_s$
Where $\nu_s$ is the laser frequency. You can see here that for typical visible range HeNe laser the gain bandwidth will be proportional to the inverse of the frequency, and therefore, can be considered to have a very narrow gain bandwidth.
Solid state lasers, on the other hand, are impurities (rare earth ions) implanted onto a crystal matrix, and thus you create line broadening that depends strongly on the local field at each position of the crystal matrix. The gain bandwidth is also inhomogeneous, but the interactions are mostly dominated by the crystal matrix and thus has a broader gain linewidth, allowing for more wavelengths to be generated by the same crystal matrix.
Here the dynamics are more complicated and I do not have actual literature with an equation to demonstrate it, but you can find plenty of literature where this property is exploited, here an example from Seidel et al. for solid state spectral broadening: https://opg.optica.org/oe/fulltext.cfm?uri=oe-24-9-9412&id=340135
The rest of the post has been adapted from the book Laser Physics by Eichhorn: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-05128-4
